# Version/Tracking single property of an entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Lets say I'm working with an entity named Person. Person has properties such as height, weight, ect... that can be changed over time.

```
class Person
{
    private $id;
    private $weight;
    private $height;

    // etc...
}
```

I would like the User to be able to go back and see the changes over time on some form of graph. What is the best way to store each successive change for each separate property?

I've looked at the DoctrineExtension Loggable interface, but that creates a change entry for the entire object, so you can't 'browse' backwards by a specific property independent of the object, that has changed.

As well, reverting back to a previous version with Loggable will cause you to lose any changes between said version and current (as intended, but I want to be able to remove specific entries).

Would the best approach be a classic **OneToMany/ManyToOne** relationship from Person to **"entry objects"**, such as `PersonHeightEntry` or `PersonWeightEntry` (which contain the value and a timestamp for the entry), pulling the most current timestamp as the current value?

Example:

```
class Person
{
// @ORM\OneToMany(...)
private $weight_entries;
}

class PersonWeightEntry
{
    private $value;
    private $timestamp;

    // @ORM\ManyToOne(...)
    private $person;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the Loggable Interface can be used to store the different versions of an object in the database while presenting the data in another form to the user. For example you can read the different heights from the database and present them with no need to show the whole object.

You can also "revert" changes for only one property by overwriting the property of the actual object with the old value which you get from the old version of that object.

Having many properties mapped with OneToMany relations will cause load on your database and make the computing heavier.

I would use the Loggable Interface, storing full objects in the database, and then alter the representation in your application according to your needs.